# Pantheon Desktop shell unresponsive / hang / freeze when using kodi

Tags: release-loki, pantheon

I installed loki x64 on a Gateway NE 522 with AMD A4 5000.

I added kodi, boot-repair, and seahorse.

```
      sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
      sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install kodi
      sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

      sudo apt-get install seahorse  
      seahorse  
      locate fusion  
      locate hubwiz  
      sudo shutdown -r now
```

I restored a kodi - `xbmc` - `xmlbackup` from another computer.
Then, I used fusion installer to then install/run config wizard.

Sometimes, Kodi will not respond to mouse clicks. Then the whole desktop will not respond to mouse clicks.

Nothing seems to make it work. Switch to tty1, or tty6, back to tty7, etc.

After a minute or some number of minutes, pantheon or the desktop ( or whatever the correct term is ) seems to restart by itself.

How can I define this problem more precisely?

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Am I asking the right question in the right place?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> I restored a kodi - xbmc - xmlbackup from another computer. Then, I used fusion installer to then install/run config wizard.

Why don't you start from a clean installation of the apps you restored and see if that fixes it? Backups cause problems when switching to other distros because they can use different versions of many packages.

Also, according to [this](https://www.notebookcheck.org/AMD-A-Series-A4-5000-Notebook-Processor.95284.0.html) your processor is a bit old and the integrated GPU is slow so you need to be patient when it hangs. It's just that it can't go faster!