# Pantheon not responding to mouse clicks

Tags: release-loki, updates, mouse, pantheon

I think I have a similar problem to this post, but not sure

[Pantheon Desktop shell unresponsive / hang / freeze when using kodi](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9820/pantheon-desktop-shell-unresponsive-hang-freeze-when-using-kodi)

I was doing some work on my Loki desktop on Sunday but had some kind of issue where everything just seemed to be painfully slow. I rebooted and ever since the windows manager will not respond to mouse clicks. The mouse works, sometimes I can click on the dock items, somethings wingpannel, sometimes both, but oonce I open up an application, I can only control that application with the keyboard. I can't click to select anything in the application window, I can't drag and move the window; nothing.
I noticed there is a much longer lag between login and when the pantheon desktop is fully loaded..

I suspect it may have been caused by a faulty update installation. Is there anyway to fix this without a complete re-installation?

I am running Loki on a 2006 Mac Pro desktop
2*Xeon 4-core CPUs
32gb ddr 3 or 2
Nvidia GTX970
EOS is on an SSD

Thanks in advance

I am editing this because I have narrowed the issue down to either
1: the Logitech cordless mouse I was using or
2: clicking on the shutdown icon on wingpannel

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same issue. The mouse becomes completely unresponsive. However i could navigate with keyboard. I found a quick solution. Pressing win + space to open the launcher fixes it for me. At least for some time.

Answer (score 1):

The mouse becomes unresponsive when changing applications/windows. 
Apparently, this bug is not specific to Pantheon. I've faced the same issue on Ubuntu 17.10. **Removing the Nvidia-304 driver fixes it**.

[This](https://translate.google.com.br/translate?sl=pt&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.diolinux.com.br%2F2015%2F09%2Fcomo-instalar-drivers-de-video-no-ubuntu-linux.html&edit-text=&act=url) is a good tutorial for installing the correct Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu and derivatives.

One way I found to get around, without uninstalling the Nvidia-304 driver, is by **changing to the desired application/window with alt + tab**. The mouse click shall work on the newly selected window.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue after installing three Drivers using the new AppCenter:

- intel-microcode v3.20151106.1
- nvidia-340 v340.102
- nvidia-304 v304.135

And resolved it by **removing the nvidia-304**.

I have GeForce 8600 and the old package causes problems.

[image]
(uninstall the selected item)

---

As for the long lag beween login and desktop, I have this issue for half a year already, seems like it does not correlate with the mouse issue...

I created a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1697640